# RecycleView not showing in Dialogue Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I have a Dialogue Fragment which a RecycleView will shown inside it.This is driving me crazy,cause I almost see all the SO question about RecycleView not show up problem,but still not solving my problem.Please take a look in my code

Here is my **Fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titlebar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Be the first to like this"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="@color/dialog"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titlebar"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/comment_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/commentInsert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/commentField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Add a comment"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment.java** set the recycleview to the Fragment

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Remove TITLE
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comment, container,false);
    commentRecyclerView =(RecyclerView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.comment_recycler_view);
    commentRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    //bind the recycler view with the adapter
    commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this.getActivity(),commentItems);
    final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    commentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    commentRecyclerView.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
```

**Here I make Request to server**

```
  private void fetchItem(int item_id){


    // making fresh volley request and getting json
    JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_GET_ITEM + item_id, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            VolleyLog.d(AppController.TAG, "VolleyResponse: " + response.toString());
            Log.d("responseGet",response.toString());
            parseJsonFeed(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(AppController.TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    }) {
        //adding header to authenticate
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return  headers;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to volley request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);

}
```

**Here I parse the json feed**

```
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {

        JSONArray itemArray = response.getJSONArray("item");
        //get all the item in Json
        for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject) itemArray.get(i);

            itemId = itemObj.getInt("item_id");
            itemUsername= itemObj.getString("item_username");
            itemBody =  itemObj.getString("item_body");
            itemProfileImage =  itemObj.getString("item_profile_image");
            itemCreatedAt = itemtObj.getString("item_created_at");

            //set all item to the Array list
            setItemToCommentArrayList(itemId,itemUsername,itemProfileImage,itemBody,itemCreatedAt);

        }

        // notify data changes to list adapter
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }catch (JSONException e){
        System.out.println("end of content");
    }

}
```

**Here I add all the details to the `Item.java` model**

```
private void setItemToCommentArrayList(int itemId, String itemUsername, String itemrofileImage, String itemBody, String itemCreatedAt) {
    CommentItem item = new CommentItem();
    item.setCommentId(itemId);
    item.setUsername(itemUsername);
    item.setCommentProfilePic(itemProfileImage);
    item.setCommentBody(itemBody);
    item.setCommentTimeStamp(itemCreatedAt);


    //save it to the comment array list
    items.add(item);
}
```

**Here is the comment_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/commentProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/comment_item_profile_pic"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/comment_item_profile_pic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comment_item_profile_info_padd">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentBody"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentTimestamp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/comment_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/comment_item_timestamp_pad_top" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Lastly,here is the adapter**

```
public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
private Context mContext;
private List<CommentItem> commentItems;

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView commentBody,commentUsername,commentTimeStamp;
    ImageView commentProfilePic;

    //find all the view here
    MyViewHolder(final View view) {
       super(view);

        commentProfilePic = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentProfilePic);
        commentUsername = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentUsername);
        commentBody = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentBody);
        commentTimeStamp = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentTimestamp);

    }
}

public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, List<CommentItem> commentItems) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.commentItems = commentItems;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
//this one for make the adview inside this
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}


//bind the comment item here
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View commentItemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(commentItemView);
}

//do all the action here
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CommentAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final CommentItem commentItem = commentItems.get(position);

    //commenter username
    holder.commentUsername.setText(commentItem.getUsername());

    //commenter profile image
    Glide
            .with(mContext)
            .load(commentItem.getCommentProfilePic())
            .fitCenter()
            .into(holder.commentProfilePic);


    //comment body
    holder.commentBody.setText(commentItem.getCommentBody());

    //comment timestamp
    holder.commentTimeStamp.setText(commentItem.getCommentTimeStamp());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return commentItems.size();
}
}
```

I almost check everything with my another RecycleView,I didnt see any different.And also see all the Stackoverflow question too,I still cant see what happen.It just didnt show any item in the recycleview.Somebody please help

**UPDATE**
I just change the layout in Fragment.xml from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout,it still not working.

I change the `layout_height` to `match_parent` ,remove this line as well `android:layout_weight="1"` ,still not show up the item.As below

Tried change to Linear Layout as parent,  `android:layout_height="500dp"`as well,not shown up also

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/comment_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably issue with `android:layout_weight="1"`
You havent used weights anywhere other than the RecyclerView in parent Layout.

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Here height is 0dp and weight is used in a RelativeLayout. These wont work.

First of all, weights wont work with RelativeLayouts. Your Recycler view is child of RelativeLayout. So, if you have a predefined size then remove the weight and set some height to your recycler view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/comment_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

**OR**
Use appropriate weights for proper height distribution with a LinearLayout as parent. That should fix it.

Comment: u mean this in the Linear Layout of `comment_item.xml`??Do you mean this??

Comment: I change the `layout_height `to `match_parent` too,still not working

Answer (score 0):

The combination `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` works only inside a linear layout. If you want to use weight attribute, put your recycler inside a LinearLayout or set a custom height instead. Basically your problem is that your recycler height is "0dp"

Comment: sir,I change the layout to Linear Layout ady,but still not show out anything

Comment: Thats because you should rearrange all items if you change the relativeLayout, try to change the height of the recycler to 20dp or something to see if it appears

Comment: Bro just nothing happen..the `comment_item.xml` is not shown out.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you add layout_weight attribute set width or height to 0dp respectively. Also assign weigths to other elements giving weight to one element only is not a good practice they will cover the whole layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in onCreate() method :
setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.ThemeOverlay)